# How can I print this list without the spaces at the beginning?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I`m trying to make a simple Tic Tac Toe Game in Python. Now with my Code the Playtable looks like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3
  | 4 | 5 | 6 
  | 7 | 8 | 9
```

My Code:

```
x = ["1", "2", "3 \n ", "4", "5", "6 \n ", "7", "8", "9"]
print(" | ".join(x))
```

How can i print the playtable like in the first line of the playtable?

Comment: @Cid will that make the rows look right?

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on keeping the same list `x`, you could try this:

```
x = ["1", "2", "3 \n ", "4", "5", "6 \n ", "7", "8", "9"]
for i in range(3):
    print(" | ".join(n.strip() for n in x[i*3:i*3+3]))
```

The output:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

Comment: This looks a lot complicated

Comment: It's not very complicated, it's just iterating through your list by threes.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to separate the game logic (the list containing the datas) of the game display (the pipes, the `\n`)

You can consider using a list of rows, each row being another list containing a cell (a *nested list*) :

```
rows = [
         ["1", "2", "3"],
         ["4", "5", "6"],
         ["7", "8", "9"]
       ]

display = "\n".join([" | ".join(row) for row in rows])

print(display)
```

`" | ".join(row) for row in rows` will iterate through every elements of rows (successively `["1", "2", "3"]`, `["4", "5", "6"]` and then `["7", "8", "9"]`) and apply `" | ".join()`

The fact it's wrapped into brackets `---> [ <--- " | ".join(row) for row in rows ---> ] <---` will create a list from the result of the previous action, containing the joined strings : `[ "1 | 2 | 3", "4 | 5 | 6", "7 | 8 | 9" ]`

And then, `"\n".join()` will join the previous list for the final display

This outputs

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

Then, you can easier access the differents elements, for example, the 3rd row, first column (the number 7) is accessed with `rows[2][0]`

Comment: Can you explain me how the .join() in your code works?

Comment: @TobiasPutz I've added some explanations, if it's still unclear, let me know and I'll rephrase

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Cid comment this is what you are looking for

```
x = ["1", "2", "3\n4", "5", "6\n7", "8", "9"]
print(" | ".join(x))
```

Output:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: The output looks like  the OP's image

Comment: But if you are trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, you should be able to access the list without the '\n'

Comment: @PCM OP asked for the appearance of this table. At this point we don't know what he is going to do with it but you're right regarding further process steps, it might become difficult to handle with the `\n` in it

Comment: But if you're going to change the structure to an unusable format you could simply drop it and write `print('1 | 2 | 3\n4 | 5 | 6\n7 | 8 | 9')`.